# Java threads priority

Tags: java, multithreading

See the code below. this is a modified code sample from Oracle tutorial pages:

```
public class BadThreads {
    static String message;

private static class CorrectorThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(1000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        message = "Mares do eat oats."; 
        System.out.println("1: "+ message);
    }    
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    CorrectorThread c=new CorrectorThread();

    c.start();
    System.out.println("0: "+ message);
    c.run(); 
    System.out.println("2: "+ message);

    message = "Mares do not eat oats.";
    System.out.println("3: "+ message);

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("4: "+ message);
}
}
```

prints

```
0: null
1: Mares do eat oats.
1: Mares do eat oats.
2: Mares do eat oats.
3: Mares do not eat oats.
4: Mares do not eat oats.
```

and is fine.

When I comment out

```
c.run();
```

in the main method, i get

```
0: null
2: null
3: Mares do not eat oats.
1: Mares do eat oats.
4: Mares do eat oats.
```

How come **main** is executed before **c**? The thread **c** has the same priority of its "parent" thread **main**.

Is it that **main** is visible to **c** and thus **c** is waiting for **main** to return? this doesn't make sense but is the only thing i can think of.

//============================

EDIT: 
replace

```
c.run();
```

with

```
c.join();
```

for same effect and finer programming.

Comment: http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#synctr

Comment: Priority is just a hint and in many cases ignored completely if you are not `root` or `administrator` It only matters if you have high CPU utilisation and I don't suggest you do that.

Comment: Peter Lawrey: i'm aware that fairness is ensures to avoid starvation for one thing-- although not guaranteeing the longest-waiting thread the first turn but haven`t heard high CPU utilization(?)

Comment: @PeterLawrey is saying that the only time you need to worry about thread-priority is when you have threads consuming all of the CPU and you want to make sure important threads get appropriate cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `c.run()`, it executes the run function and wait for completion.  The waiting will also cover the thread time parallel and you see two consective outputs in first case.  In second case, the thread started and main runs parallel to run function, as run is in sleep and in that it covers the main showed statements.

`c.start()` starts the thread runs parallel to main.  `c.run()`, calls the run function and on completion move to next statement.

Comment: yes, true. missed that timing difference at this hour of the day. thx.

Comment: @Gray - his answer looked ok before your edit. if thats alright w/you of course.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of threads is that they execute in parallel. So the main thread executes in parallel with the corrector thread. And since the first thing the corrector thread does is to sleep for 1 second, the main thread has plenty of time to execute its instructions before the corrector thread changes the message.

Comment: yeah, the time difference. same as the comment i wrote for zeeshan mughal.

Comment: Curious why you chose the other answer which was later than this one and much more poorly written @Roam.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing strange here dude, because there is no WARRANTY about main thread goes first or second becasue of order of calling thread/method.

first `c.start()` starts a new thread, it means main continues its job. so in the first situation, you have something like this

```
0000->thread main starts the bad thread |  bad thread sleeps for 1 second
      and prints the message value(null)
0001->thread main runs the run() method |  bad thread still is sleeping
      with its thread
0002-> both thread are sleeping ....
0003->.....
1000->either bad thread or main thread changes the message value to "Mares do eat oats." (not sure which goes first!)
1001->thread main prints("1:" +message) |  bad thread prints("1:" +message)
1002->thread main prints("1:" +message) | bad thread has terminated X
1003->thread main changes the message value to "Mares do not eat oats."
1004->main threads prints the message again and sleeps for 2 seconds
2004->main thread prints the message again.
```

while in the second situation, there is no call `run()` by main thread, so main thread doesn't sleep for 1 second like bad thread does, and just attempts to print the message and change the value to "Mares do not eat oats." and prints again, then sleeps for 2 seconds, then after this when bad thread wakes up after 1 second(while main thread is in sleep state), it changes the value of the message and prints it, the main thread after 2 second prints the message which is changed by the bad thread.

the answer is here, there is no warranty about which thread goes first or second because of order of execution. [this tutorial](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#switch0) may help you out dude.

Answer (score 0):

See inline comments

```
CorrectorThread c=new CorrectorThread();

c.start(); // new thread started, but up to scheduler to decide when to give it a slice of time
System.out.println("0: "+ message);
c.run(); // ran in main thread
System.out.println("2: "+ message); // as expected, message was set by the other thread

message = "Mares do not eat oats.";
System.out.println("3: "+ message); // as expected

Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("4: "+ message); // as expected
```

`c.start()` and `c.run()` will be both end up calling `CorrectorThread#run()` but in different threads. It's up to the `Thread` scheduler for which will get there first.

In the example where you don't call `c.run()` the scheduler has time to call

```
System.out.println("0: "+ message); // null

System.out.println("2: "+ message); // null
```

before the other thread has time to initialize `message`.

Comment: @Roam It's a race, one Thread sets the `message`, the other sets it back.

Comment: @Roam Yes, that's how stackoverflow works. You ask for clarifications and we give give them.

Comment: @Roam Your Q was `How come main is executed before c?`. My answer was (and is) `c.start() and c.run() will be both end up calling CorrectorThread#run() but in different threads. It's up to the Thread scheduler for which will get there first.` You can then deduce what happens if you remove `c.run()`.

Comment: ...also read your original answer and see what it`s saying. 
this is getting to be too much of a twist & annoying. 
no more comment to you here.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
public class BadThreads {
    static String message;

    private static class CorrectorThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            message = "Mares do eat oats."; 
            System.out.println("3: "+ message);
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        CorrectorThread c=new CorrectorThread();
        c.start();

        System.out.println("0: "+ message); 
        System.out.println("1: "+ message);

        message = "Mares do not eat oats.";
        System.out.println("2: "+ message);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("4: "+ message);
    }
}
```

Comment: cant run without a start.

Comment: Can you explain it please so others can learn.  Just dropping uncommented code doesn't teach anything.